# Temperature Rating for Solar Panels

Tags: solar-cell, space

I am trying to decide on a power source for use in space, and as such they need to have a good operating temperature range.
I can't find any decent source on the web about this particular topic for solar arrays already in use. Hence me being here, does anyone know a typical operating temperature range for a solar array used in space?

The temperatures can vary from extreme highs to extreme lows so I want to include this in my argument to justify a decision being made.

Comment: Different for different models, look at datasheets.

Comment: 'Space' is rather large. LEO is different from the moon, an asteroid or deep space, for example.

Comment: I'd go looking for something from Nasa.  (I was going to mumble something about carrier freeze out at low temp.  But the carriers are created by photons so that won't be a problem.)

Comment: Is yours some sort of thought experiment/feasibility analysis for some school/university assignment/project, or is it a real design you are carrying out for a company? The acceptable accuracy and reliability of the sources you may find could depend on the context you are working in.

Comment: Anyway, as @SpehroPefhany already said, more details are needed to answer meaningfully.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I wish I could vote for your comment as the greatest understatement of the year (*'space' is rather large*) :-D

Comment: Don't want to discourage, but I pray this person isn't working for NASA designing satellites or something.

Comment: Basically everybody in the satellite business buys high-efficiency aerospace grade triple-junction solar cells either from Boeing Spectrolab in the USA (http://www.spectrolab.com/space.htm) or from Azurspace in Germany (http://www.azurspace.com/). These two vendors account for the majority of solar cells used on-orbit.

Answer (score 1):

- There are many factors for the effect of irradiation and ambient temperature on a PV system or a PVT (PV+Thermal) system.

  - Amorphous silicon (a-Si) is the liquid-solid material that is a non-crystalline form of silicon used for solar photo-voltaic (PV) cells and thin-film transistors in LCD displays.
  - Crystalline silicon (c-Si) come in both Mono and Poly-crystalline is a high quality purified Si, more efficient but made in thin films with toxic materials; Cadmium Telluride (CdTe) or copper indium gallium selenide (CIGS or CIS) and much-less Enviro-friendly for disposal.

This is one type of a-Silicon material.
[image]

The max PV power \$Pm=FF*I_{sc}*V_{oc}\$

- for a given Fill Factor \$ FF\$, which depends on;

  - ambient temp \$T_a\$
  - cell temp \$T_c\$
  - wind speed      \$V_w\$
  - Irradiation     \$I(t)\$
  - glazing transmittance \$\tau\$
  - substrate Absorption \$\alpha\$
  - electrical efficiency \$η_{Tref}\$
  - cell tempco         \$\beta{ref}\$
  - Ref. Temp \$T_{ref}\$ e.g. \$ @25\deg C @ 1kW/m^2\$
  - zero power temp \$T_{o}\$ at high temp
- Both \$FF\$ and \$Voc\$ have a neg. temp. coeff., NTC
- where \$\beta=\frac{1}{T_o-T_{ref}}\$

**The overall mean monthly efficiency  \$\bar η\$ becomes;**
[image]
Above is for mean monthly values, *Siegel MD, Klein SA, Beckman WA. A simplified method for estimating the monthly-average performance of photovoltaic
systems. Solar Energy 1981;26,413-8.*

- \$n\$ hours per day
- \$U_L\$ mean thermal loss coeff.
- \$H_T\$ mean daily **Insolation** on direct plane
- \$V\$ is a function of sunset angle ratio, average sky clarity index, mean gain for solar tracking
  The hybrid system consists of a solar PV panels combined with a cooling system. i.e., water or air, for cooling the solar cells, and transported for other uses such as domestic heating.

These are some examples PV and PVT arrays.

[image]

The payback period of < 5 yrs for a 10 yr expected minimum lifespan for major components is a general rule of thumb including converters, storage cells, with install & maintenance cost. Anything better is "gravy".

> Some of the inefficiency of PV's is due to the lack of conversion of InfraRed thermal and UV energy from the sun's \$1.3kW/m^2\$ , which is why it is often rated at \$1kW/m^2\$ for the sensitivity of Silicon cells.

This performance ratio decreases with latitude because of temperature extremes but improves with altitude due to colder mean temperatures.

> PV modules have tradeoffs for thermal sensitivity and efficacy so low T sensitivity is preferred for generally high ambient zones and higher eff. but higher effic. PVT improves year round effectiveness, when used with heat pumps.

- - One example of this range was my hometown in Winnipeg where it can reach +40'C for a week in summer and Winter can reach -40'C for a week in Feb.*

Hybrid Photovoltaic/Thermal (PV/T) solar system is perhaps the best option for cooling photovoltaic panels , reclaiming energy and boost efficiency, but initial cost is higher.

This is not a complete answer , just a guide to understand the parameters and variables used. I hope it was worth the effort on your part to read it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The following articles may help: 
**General**: Space Environmental Effects - NASA

**Solar Arrays**: Qualification and Production of Emcore ZTJ Solar Panels for Space
Missions